# All email adresses are pasted in the To field but should go into BCC field

Tags: python, email, smtp, celery

I have the following script for sending mails using python:

```
import smtplib
from celery import Celery
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from KerbalStuff.config import _cfg, _cfgi, _cfgb

app = Celery("tasks", broker=_cfg("redis-connection"))

def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

@app.task
def send_mail(sender, recipients, subject, message, important=False):
    if _cfg("smtp-host") == "":
        return
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host=_cfg("smtp-host"), port=_cfgi("smtp-port"))
    if _cfgb("smtp-tls"):
        smtp.starttls()
    if _cfg("smtp-user") != "":
        smtp.login(_cfg("smtp-user"), _cfg("smtp-password"))
    message = MIMEText(message)
    if important:
        message['X-MC-Important'] = "true"
    message['X-MC-PreserveRecipients'] = "false"
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message['From'] = sender
    if len(recipients) > 1:
        message['Precedence'] = 'bulk'
    for group in chunks(recipients, 100):
        if len(group) > 1:
            message['To'] = "undisclosed-recipients:;"
        else:
            message['To'] = ";".join(group)
        print("Sending email from {} to {} recipients".format(sender, len(group)))
        smtp.sendmail(sender, group, message.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```

When I use the script, I see that the mail gets delivered to everybody in the `group` but all the recipients appear in the `To` field while it should show your own adress in the `To` field and all the others in the `Bcc` field.

Is there any error in the script? Initially I thought that this might be an issue with my mail server.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with the script per se; it does seem to set the header correctly - (https://repl.it/BuZW/0) - when there's more than one in the chunk,  it puts undisclosed (BTW,  if there's only 1, itso header shows the email, dont know how desirable is that? )    Perhaps it might be your server changing the headers? Not very likely, yet it's possible; can you show a sample of the headers, as received in the recipient'so mailbox? One which is in a `len (group)>1` chunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line

```
else:
    message['To'] = ";".join(group)
```

You're concatenating the recipients to the group, and into the `To` field of your email, and not the `Bcc` field. Take a look at this [StackOverflow Post example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29936403/3342430)