# Python SMTP send email with CC

Tags: python, django

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and I want to send email with CC.
Something in general like this:
[image]

(The subject is just for example)

I have the following function:

```
def send_email(data):
    body = "hello world"
    message = MIMEText(body)
    message['Subject'] = "File '%s' upload data" % data['filename']
    message['From'] = 'noreply@atte-mm.com'
    message['To'] = data['send_to']
    message['CC'] = 'test@atte-mm.com'
    s = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_HOST)
    s.sendmail(EMAIL_SENDER, [data['send_to']], message.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

The function **works** however it ignores the `CC`.
The `TO` receive the email without the `CC` and of curse the `CC` receives nothing.

I didn't find anything useful in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) about SMTP.

Is it possible to send a mail with `CC`? If not how do I make it work with two email address in the `TO`?

Comment: You're not supplying the `CC` email to `sendmail` function. Put the `CC` email along with `data['send_to']` emails. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546367/python-how-to-send-mail-with-to-cc-and-bcc) might help.

Comment: But I want it to be in CC not just another recipient... Assuming this is my only option should I just do `message['To'] = data['send_to']   + 'x@x.com'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: how to send mail with TO, CC and BCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546367/python-how-to-send-mail-with-to-cc-and-bcc)

Answer (score 1):

The "c" might have to be lower case like this:

```
message['Cc'] = 'test@atte-mm.com'
```