# How can I send email to multi addresses by smtplib?

Tags: python, django, smtplib

I use bellow code I can send email to one account, but how can I send to multi account?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

_user = "67676767@qq.com"  #  
_pwd = "orjxywulscbxsdwbaii"  #  
_to = linux213@126.com"  #  

msg = MIMEText("content")  #  
msg["Subject"] = "邮件主题测试"  #  
msg["From"] = _user
msg["To"] = _to

try:
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.qq.com", 465)
    s.login(_user, _pwd)
    s.sendmail(_user, _to, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
    print ("Success!")
except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
    print ("Falied,%s" % e)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: how to send mail with TO, CC and BCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546367/python-how-to-send-mail-with-to-cc-and-bcc)

Comment: You can assign `_to` a list of email addresses.and try like this `s.sendmail(_user, [ _to ], msg.as_string())`

Comment: @GeekSambhu Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.qq.com')
s.set_debuglevel(1)
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = 'me@example.com'
recipients = ['k.ankur@abc.com', 'a.smith@abc.co.in']
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Consider commenting your solution