# How to CC in gmail python api

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to add cc in Gmail python API. So far I haven't seen any example on google. Here is what I tried in `create_message` method:

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text, cc=None):
  message = MIMEText(message_text,'html')
  message['to'] = to
  if cc:
    message['cc'] = cc
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

I looked through `MIMEText.py` and `discovery.py` but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually using the gmail API, or just using the stdlib to talk to gmail's server? `MIMEText` doesn't care what headers you stick on a message; that's up to the code that _uses_ the message, so we need to see that part of your code.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546367/python-how-to-send-mail-with-to-cc-and-bcc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @abarnert I am using gmail API and (example code from the tutorial)[https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending].

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati this code seems to be for standard smtp API.

Comment: please consider your tagging it will help you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `message['cc'] = "cc.1@gmail.com,cc.2@gmail.com,cc.3@gmail.com"`? This is how I solved mine.