# How to make this python script send emails using the 'To' line instead of 'bcc' to everyone on the list?

Tags: python, email

I am writing code in python to send messages to a large number of contacts from an excel sheet. Everything about the code works just fine except when I look at the sent emails they are all sent as bcc instead of individually to each person using the 'to' line on the email. What do I need to change in my code to make the emails sent using the 'to' line?

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
 
your_email = "xxxxx.xxx"
your_password = "xxxxxxx"

# establishing connection with gmail
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(your_email, your_password)
 
# reading the spreadsheet
email_list = pd.read_excel('/Users/miles/gfg.xlsx')
 
# getting the names and the emails
names = email_list['NAME']
emails = email_list['EMAIL']
types = email_list['TYPE']

message_1 = "x"
message_2 = "x"

# iterate through the records
for i in range(len(emails)):
    name = names[i]
    email = emails[i]
    
    if types[i] == 1:
        Subject = "x"
        Body = message_1
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(Subject, Body)
        server.sendmail(your_email, [email], message)
    else:
        Subject = "x"
        Body = message_2
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(Subject, Body)
        server.sendmail(your_email, [email], message)

server.close()
```

Looking at other people's scripts for performing this function they seem to be written entirely differently than mine, so if my overall formatting is just poorly done please let me know! Fairly new to python so this is a possibility.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a **minimal** reproducible example.

Comment: After reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546367/how-to-send-mail-with-to-cc-and-bcc and https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html I still don't understand what you need to change when using `sendmail`, but it seems to be more straightforward if you use [`send_message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message) instead.